# What is the draw back of Bag of Words model?

Tags: algorithms, natural-language-processing

Bag of words model rank words in a particular document in such a way that

If it is occurring into that particular document multiple times and it's frequency is low for other documents then it's weight is high. And It seems perfect.

Where will it lack? Can someone please give me insight upon dis?

Comment: Drawback compared to what ??

Comment: Using that algo ,accuracy is not bit higher ? Where and why is it lacking ?

Comment: Compared to what ?